# Determining programmatically whether Zope is running in interactive console mode

Tags: plone, zope

I know that I can determining programmatically whether Zope is in running in debug mode (`bin/instance fg`) using the following:

```py
>>> import Globals
>>> Globals.DevelopmentMode
True
```

It is possible to determine if I started the deamon in interactive console mode (`bin/instance debug`)?

You may think that this not make sense, but I'm having an issue with a package when I run an instance this way:

https://github.com/collective/collective.fingerpointing/issues/30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by catching the resulting exception instead:

https://github.com/collective/collective.fingerpointing/pull/34